# C# : MVVM ASP.net API Error On Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, asp.net-apicontroller

I am new to c# asp stack, and I am developing a web API to expose data from our SQL server back end. I have a table to be read from currently by the `HTTP GET` command.

Everything works as expected apart from when I compile I get an error around the authorization. could anyone advise how to manage the error please?

Any help would be really appreciated, I am really struggling to understand this one. Thanks.

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException
>        An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in 
>        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Unable to find the 
>        required services. Please add all the required services by calling 
>        'IServiceCollection.AddAuthorization' inside the call to 'ConfigureServices(...)' in the application 
>        startup code.'
>         at  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.AuthorizationAppBuilderExtensions.VerifyServicesRegistered(IApplicationBuilder app)
>       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.AuthorizationAppBuilderExtensions.UseAuthorization(IApplicationBuilder app)
>       at BED_MGMT_WEBAPP_APIs.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in c:\Users\james gray\Documents\BED_MGMT_WEBAPP_APIs\Startup.cs:line 56
>       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
>        at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
>       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
>       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.b__2(IApplicationBuilder app)
>       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
>       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.d__31.MoveNext()

my startup.cs

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
 using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
 using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
 using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
 using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
 using BED_MGMT_WEBAPP_APIs.Models;
 using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;

 namespace BED_MGMT_WEBAPP_APIs
 {
     public class Startup
     {
         public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
         {
             Configuration = configuration;
         }

         public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

         // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add      services to the container.
         public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

         {
             services.AddDbContext<bed_data_dbconnect>(options =>
             options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

             //string connectionString =      Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
             //services.AddDbContext<bed_data_dbconnect>(opt =>      opt.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
             //services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
    }

         //public static      Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection AddAuthorization      (this Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection services);

         // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
         public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();            

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }


     }
 }
```

my app settings:

```
   {

     "ConnectionString": {
         "DefaultConnection":        "Server=blah.blah.blah.blah;Database=ourDB;Trusted_Connection=True;"


     },

     "Logging": {
       "LogLevel": {
         "Default": "Information",
         "Microsoft": "Warning",
         "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
       }
     },
     "AllowedHosts": "*"
   }
```

My table items:

```
 using System;

 namespace BED_MGMT_WEBAPP_APIs.Models
  {
     public class Bed_Data
     {
    public string HOSPITAL {get;set;}
    public string WARD_CODE {get;set;}
    public string WARD {get;set;}
    public int REALTIME_BED_STOCK {get;set;}
    public int ACTUAL_BED_STOCK {get;set;}
    public int AVAILABLE_BEDS_M {get;set;}
    public int AVAILABLE_BEDS_F {get;set;}
    public int AVAILABLE_BEDS_C {get;set;}
    public int TOTAL_BEDS_CLOSED {get;set;}
    public int CLOSED_AND_UNOCCUPIED {get;set;}
    public int ESCALATION_BEDS_IN_USE {get;set;}
    public int DISCHARGES_CONFIRMED_M {get;set;}
    public int DISCHARGES_CONFIRMED_F {get;set;}
    public int DISCHARGES_CONFIRMED_C {get;set;}
    public int DISCHARGES_POTENTIAL_M {get;set;}
    public int DISCHARGES_POTENTIAL_F {get;set;}
    public int DISCHARGES_POTENTIAL_C {get;set;}
    public int AWAITING_ADMISSION_AE_M {get;set;}
    public int AWAITING_ADMISSION_AE_F {get;set;}
    public int AWAITING_ADMISSION_AE_C {get;set;}
    public int AWAITING_ADMISSION_INTERNAL_M {get;set;}
    public int AWAITING_ADMISSION_INTERNAL_F {get;set;}
    public int AWAITING_ADMISSION_INTERNAL_C {get;set;}
    public int AWAITING_ADMISSION_EXTERNAL_M {get;set;}
    public int AWAITING_ADMISSION_EXTERNAL_F {get;set;}
    public int AWAITING_ADMISSION_EXTERNAL_C {get;set;}
    public int AWAITING_REPATRIATION_IN {get;set;}
    public int AWAITING_REPATRIATION_OUT {get;set;}
    public int OUTLIERS_MED {get;set;}
    public int OUTLIERS_SURG {get;set;}
    public int OUTLIERS_ORTH {get;set;}
    public string STAFFING_SHORTAGES {get;set;}
    public string USER_CODE {get;set;}
    public string DATETIME_RECORD_INSERTED {get;set;} //=      System.Convert.ToDateTime() 

     }
  }
```

My DB context:

```
 using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

 namespace BED_MGMT_WEBAPP_APIs.Models
 {
     public class bed_data_dbconnect : DbContext
     {
         public bed_data_dbconnect(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
         { }

         public DbSet<Bed_Data> tblBase_BEDMGMT_BEDS_BY_WARD { get; set; }
     }
 }
```

my controller:

```
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using BED_MGMT_WEBAPP_APIs.Models;


 namespace BED_MGMT_WEBAPP_APIs.Controllers
 {
     [Route("api/[Controller]")]
     [ApiController]

     public class bed_data_controller : Controller
     {
         private bed_data_dbconnect _bed_data;

         public bed_data_controller(bed_data_dbconnect context)
         {

         _bed_data = context;

         }

         //Get api/values
         [HttpGet]
         public ActionResult Get()
             {
             var result=_bed_data.tblBase_BEDMGMT_BEDS_BY_WARD.ToList();
             return Json(result);
             }

         ~bed_data_controller()
         {

             _bed_data.Dispose();

         }


     }
 }
```

Comment: Show you code snippet to ponder over your issue. Thanks

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I have added my startup.cs and the appsettings